# Why my shuffle partition is not 200(default) during group by operation? (Spark 2.4.5)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I am new to spark and trying to understand the internals of it. So,
I am reading a small 50MB parquet file from s3 and performing a group by and then saving back to s3.
When I observe the Spark UI, I can see 3 stages created for this,

stage 0 : load (1 tasks)

stage 1 : shufflequerystage for grouping (12 tasks)

stage 2:  save (coalescedshufflereader) (26 tasks)

Code Sample:

```
df = spark.read.format("parquet").load(src_loc)
df_agg = df.groupby(grp_attribute)\                             
 .agg(F.sum("no_of_launches").alias("no_of_launchesGroup")
df_agg.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(target_loc)
```

I am using EMR instance with 1 master, 3 core nodes(each with 4vcores). So, default parallelism is 12. I am not changing any config in runtime. But I am not able to understand why 26 tasks are created in the final stage? As I understand by default the shuffle partition should be 200. Screenshot of the UI attached.

[image]

Comment: Which Version of Spark?

Comment: Spark 2.4.5 @Narsireddy

Comment: Can you show code pls?

Comment: @thebluephantom added

Comment: Will look later

Comment: Interesting, when I run on databricks and do something similar, then when I do print(df_agg.rdd.getNumPartitions()), I get 200 !

Comment: you probably also want to look at the SQL and not the job tab of the spark sql server.

Comment: @AndrewLong sql tab does not give any info about the tasks/partitions created right?

Comment: @thebluephantom any idea why that number is not getting translated in the UI?

Comment: Not sure what to make of it myself. Need to look at source. Bounty question. I am scala with spark conversant, but pure scala would require someone else to look. Very good question although we can see this often enough occurring.

Comment: @andidev711 What it does have is the actual physical execution plan which is what spark is doing under the hood.  I suspect it will be insightful to know the actual operators that spark is using.

Comment: I have had a look at it. Will edit the question and include the information

Comment: great. it was indeed spark.conf.set('spark.sql.adaptive.enabled', 'true'), which is reducing the number of tasks. When I set it to false, I get 200 tasks in the UI. And, if I set the shuffle partition configuration , the above config is ignored. But, strangely, I don't see this parameter when I print the sc.getConf().getAll().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried a similar logic on Databricks with Spark 2.4.5.

I observe that with `spark.conf.set('spark.sql.adaptive.enabled', 'true')`, the final number of my partitions is 2.

I observe that with `spark.conf.set('spark.sql.adaptive.enabled', 'false')` and `spark.conf.set('spark.sql.shuffle.partitions', 75)`, the final number of my partitions is 75.

Using `print(df_agg.rdd.getNumPartitions())` reveals this.

So, the job output on Spark UI does not reflect this. May be a repartition occurs at the end. Interesting, but not really an issue.

Comment: great. it was indeed spark.conf.set('spark.sql.adaptive.enabled', 'true'), which is reducing the number of tasks. When I set it to false, I get 200 tasks in the UI. And, if I set the shuffle partition configuration , the above config is ignored. But, strangely, I don't see this parameter when I print the sc.getConf().getAll().

Comment: I would ask another questiom

Comment: I will accept the answer as it helped me solved my doubt, but not sure why you are still not seeing the same number in the UI.

Comment: That is as I said the big mystery. I think they are changing things and that a lot of docs are still RDD based but with DF s different paradigm. post a new question with a bounty.

Comment: Ok I will do that. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Adding this https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-sql/whats-new-apache-spark-3-shuffle-partitions-coalesce/read

Answer (score 2):

In Spark sql, number of shuffle partitions are set using spark.sql.shuffle.partitions which defaults to 200. In most of the cases, this number is too high for smaller data and too small for bigger data. Selecting right value becomes always tricky for the developer.

So we need an ability to coalesce the shuffle partitions by looking at the mapper output. If the mapping generates small number of partitions, we want to reduce the overall shuffle partitions so it will improve the performance.

In the lastet version , Spark3.0 with **Adaptive Query Execution** , this feature of reducing the tasks  is automated.
http://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/spark-aqe-part-2/

Considering this in Spark2.4.5 also catalist opimiser or EMR might have enabled this feature to reduce the tasks insternally rather 200 tasks.

Comment: 2.4.5 version and may?

Comment: FYI EMR has their own version of AQE that they've enabled for later versions of 2.x